# Changing Z-Index of three divs onclick

Tags: onclick, z-index

OK I have three layers that fit perfectly on top of each other (layer1, layer2 & layer3). Simply all I want to do is have one on top when a different div (layer4, layer5 & layer6) is clicked. I can get this to work with two layers, but when I add three the third layer seems to stick, and I get errors in Dreamweaver. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="layer1">
</DIV>

<div id="layer2">
</DIV>

<div id="layer3">
</DIV>

<div id="layer4" onClick="document.getElementById('layer1').style.zIndex='10'", "document.getElementById('layer2').style.zIndex='30'",
"document.getElementById('layer3').style.zIndex='20'">
</DIV>
<div id="layer5" onClick="document.getElementById('layer1').style.zIndex='30'", "document.getElementById('layer2').style.zIndex='10'", "document.getElementById('layer3').style.zIndex='20'">
</DIV>
<div id="layer6" onClick="document.getElementById
('layer1').style.zIndex='10'", "document.getElementById
('layer2').style.zIndex='20'", "document.getElementById
('layer3').style.zIndex='30'">
</DIV>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: 'Marked invalid due to duplicate attribute' in Dreamweaver. As I said, when it's only two layers on top of each other it works fine, but the error is still shown in Dreamweaver.